# How much work to get Episerver to leave ID-attributes alone?

Tags: .net, html, viewstate, episerver

Is there a way to make Episerver leave the HTML id attribute alone and more importantly how much work is that?

I know you could also remove the viewstate, how much work is that?

I'm not here to start a discussion about semantics and optimization, whether or not a CMS should touch the front-end code is a long debate. I just need to know how difficult these adaptions are.

Comment: Please post more concrete examples of problems with ID-tags or View State if you want more specific suggestions on how you could workaround them!

Comment: The problem with generated IDs is that they mess upp the semantics of the HTML-document and makes use of IDs in stylesheets more of a hassle to use, since you can't depend on an ID for specificity because it's (often) in constant change under development (and with future releases/updates).

The wrapping of the entire document in a form-element may not be a problem (other than semantic) if you enable the form to support both post-back and ajax through progressive enhancement (hijax).

Answer (score 1):

EPiServer Web Controls are developed to work with the ASP.NET WebForms framework and you have limited control over generation of ID-tags in some cases. It is better if you use dotnet 4.0 which is supported in EPiServer CMS 6.

It is **a lot of work** to eliminate all bad html generated by WebForms Controls completly. You will end up rewriting everything and loose a lot of ASP.NET built-in functionality. If you use WebForms it is probably better to be pragmatic and more cost effective and accept ID-tags and a small view state.

A common approach to get rid of view state is to remove the global form-tag used by ASP.NET. A known side effect is that the right-click menu in view mode used by editors stops working and also some common third party modules will also stop working as expected since they use the form-tag to inject javascript. You will also get issues with XForms.

If you want better control of the generated html render your page the MVC way using your own extension method that extracts values from EPiServer properties.

MVC is not yet supported by EPiServer CMS 6 but will nicely integrated in a future release.

Comment: Thanks! it is as I thought then. Or have experienced.

Comment: If a Control or module generates bad markup, I would say it should be rewritten any way, or not used at all. It think it's not right or fair to dump bad markup in the face of the user just because you want to use pre-existing modules. If you continue to support bad markup that way, we support irresponsible web development.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are only talking about the templates?

The hard part is rewriting the forms support for XForms made in the form designer.
You also need to drop the edit-on-page functionality.

You might also want to override some things in the most used controls such as EPiServer:Property but other than that it's just to NOT put any server forms in the template code and you won't have any problems with ASP.NET garbage markup.